# Is my home likely to be damaged by nearby construction activities?

Tags: foundation

They start at 7 and go all day.  What can I do...is my house at riskThe .land behind my house is being built on.There is a lot of vibration all day.It feels like an earthquake..as they take down trees ANd put in pipes etc.
it actually shook several  pictures off wall yesterday...help

Comment: If you have any existing cracks in walls or the foundation, take time-stamped photographs now. If they get worse take new pictures to show the difference. You may need to be able to prove the damage was not pre-existing.

Answer (score 0):

Your home is not likely to be damaged by the vibration unless it had pre-existing problems. Obviously there's risk to your property due to falls and dust. Precautions you can take include:

- Remove all hanging items from walls
- Secure items that may vibrate off horizontal surfaces
- Wrap and store items that are sensitive to dust, or remove them from the home
- Have a conversation with the builder or developer and find out what to expect

Answer (score 0):

In regions where there is an unstable ground structure (for example, [Yazoo clay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yazoo_Clay)), the clearing of nearby land can cause foundation problems for existing home. Clearing the land changes the moisture cycle (wetting and drying) of the ground which can lead to large-scale shrinking and swelling of large plots of land.

Take a trip on Interstate 20 through Jackson, MS, and you will see what can happen. Also, when malls were built in Jackson on formerly forested tracts, nearby established neighborhood were ruined due to failing foundations caused by shifting ground that hadn't happened in the previous 15 years.

Make notes and pictures of the current state of your foundation.